# How to display POST API data containing string using fetch and map function in React

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch data that i POST in API but it always throws an error "state.map is not a function."

```js
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  var z = {
    name: "yash",
    subj: "english",
  };

  const requestResp = {
    method: "POST",
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: z,
  };

  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, requestResp)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setState(data));

  return (
    <div>
      {state.map((todo) => {
        return <pre>{JSON.stringify(todo)}</pre>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was expecting to see data i posted using POST in output.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that data variable is returning some data of type array. Because might be possible that in last promise action .then data is not of type array you can check it by following code:

```
fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`,requestResp)
.then(response=> response.json())
.then(data=>{console.log(data); setState(data);})
```

Comment: Hi Asad, Thanks for responding. i checked and found that data is in object format. Can you suggest any method to convert object data to array and where to implement it. Tried Object.value() method. no luck

Comment: If you want to convert object into array then use temporary variable such as:
let d=[data];
and then setState(d); it will convert your object into array.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [Loading, setLoading] = useState < boolean > false;
const [state, setState] = useState([]);

const handle = () => {
  setLoading(true);
  fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`, requestResp).then(
    (response) => {
      response.json();
      console.log(response.json());
      setState(response.json());
      setLoading(false);
    }
  );
};
```

in your return

```
if (Loading) {
  return <h1>loading</h1>;
} else {
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding but return part does not work as return inside if and else will give syntax error.